# Prove or disprove $\Bbb E[(X-\Bbb E[X \mid \mathcal F])^2\mid \mathcal F] = 0 \Rightarrow X $ is $\mathcal F$- measurable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I have to prove or disprove for a random variable X with finite second moment that  $$\Bbb E[(X-\Bbb E[X \mid \mathcal F])^2\mid \mathcal F] = 0 \Leftrightarrow X \:\mathcal F-\mathrm{ measurable}$$ I've shown the $\Leftarrow$ direction using that for an $\mathcal F$-measurable $X$ the following holds:
$$\Bbb E[X\mid \mathcal F] = X$$
$$\mathrm{if } \: \Bbb E[|Y|], \Bbb E[|XY|] \lt \infty, \mathrm{then}\: \Bbb E[XY]=X\Bbb E[Y] $$
I'm now stuck at proving or disproving the other direction. Any tipps or ideas on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the expectation on both sides, one see that $E[(X-E[X \mid \mathcal F])^2\mid \mathcal F] = 0$ implies 
$$
X=E[X \mid \mathcal F]\quad a.s.
$$
and $E[X \mid \mathcal F]$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by "taking the expectation on both sides"?

Comment: I mean $E(E(Y|F))=E(Y)$.

Comment: ah ok, of couse, thanks a lot! Is it true that if X = Y a.e. and Y is measurable that X is measurable as well?

Comment: You might want to edit your question since one needs to specify a $\sigma$-algebra when one talks about "measurable" random variables. When one talks about a random variable $X$, it is always measurable with respect to the "biggest" $\sigma$-algebra, $\Sigma$, in discussion. The ${\mathcal F}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma$.

Comment: I see, I've fixed it.